# How does text/template determine the "default textual representation" of a map?

Tags: string, dictionary, go, go-templates, go-html-template

Per the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) of the `text/template` package in the Go standard library, (`html/template` would be the same here as far as I know) simply using the pipeline operator will spit out a "default textual representation" of whatever that is:

> {{pipeline}}
>
> ```
> The default textual representation of the value of the pipeline is copied to the output.
> ```

In the case of a map, you get a nice printed-out format with key names and everything...incidentally, this is valid JavaScript, so it makes it easy to pass whole structs into your JS code if you want.

My question is, how is this textual representation determined, and more specifically can I hook into it?  I thought perhaps it would check to see if the pipeline was a `fmt.Stringer` and I could give my map subtype a `String() string` method, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I'm hunting through the `text/template` code but I seem to be missing how it does this.

**How does `text/template` determine "default textual representation"?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default textual representation is determined by how the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package prints the value. So you were barking up the right tree.

See this example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{.}}"))
m := map[string]interface{}{"a": "abc", "b": 2}
t.Execute(os.Stdout, m)
```

It outputs:

```
map[a:abc b:2]
```

Now if we use a custom map type with a `String()` method:

```
type MyMap map[string]interface{}

func (m MyMap) String() string { return "custom" }

mm := MyMap{"a": "abc", "b": 2}
t.Execute(os.Stdout, mm)
```

Output is:

```
custom
```

Try these (and below examples) on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XxHcDiBPd4).

#### What to look out for?

Note that `MyMap.String()` has a value receiver (not a pointer). And I pass a value of `MyMap`, so it works. If you change the receiver type to pointer to `MyMap`, it won't work. And it is because then only a value of type `*MyMap` will have a `String()` method, but not a value of `MyMap`.

If the `String()` method has a pointer receiver, you have to pass `&mm` (a value of type `*MyMap`) if you want your custom representation to work.

Also note that in case of `html/template`, the template engine does contextual escaping, so the result of the `fmt` package may further be escaped.

For example if your custom `String()` method would return something "unsafe":

```
func (m MyMap2) String() string { return "<html>" }
```

Trying to insert it:

```
mm2 := MyMap2{"a": "abc", "b": 2}
t.Execute(os.Stdout, mm2)
```

Gets escaped:

```
&lt;html&gt;
```

#### Implementation

This is where it is implemented in the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package: [`text/template/exec.go`](https://golang.org/src/text/template/exec.go), unexported function `state.PrintValue()`, currently line #848:

```
_, err := fmt.Fprint(s.wr, iface)
```

If you're using the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package, it's implemented in [`html/template/content.go`](https://golang.org/src/html/template/content.go), unexported function `stringify()`, currently line #135:

```
return fmt.Sprint(args...), contentTypePlain
```

#### Further options

Also note that if the value implements [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), the `Error()` method will be called and it takes precedence over `String()`:

```
type MyMap map[string]interface{}

func (m MyMap) Error() string { return "custom-error" }

func (m MyMap) String() string { return "custom" }

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{.}}"))
mm := MyMap{"a": "abc", "b": 2}
t.Execute(os.Stdout, mm)
```

Will output:

```
custom-error
```

Instead of `custom`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HRR7aCuSfA).

Comment: Wow, awesome answer! In my case, I realized I was using `html/template` which does contextual escaping as you say, and my `{{.}}` was in a JS context, which caused the package to call [jsValEscaper](https://golang.org/src/html/template/js.go#L135), which sometimes does JSON marshaling. Hence the printed-out key names and my confusion... Thank you for the detailed answer!